# Python: Inverse matrix of an 2n x 2n matrix

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, linear-algebra

Can anyone help me in finding an inverse matrix on 2n x 2n matrix such that for i,j=1,2,...,n ,

-m_(ji) , for a_(ij) entry and i  ≠ j ,

sum_(i ≠ k) m_(ik) + (y_i + p_i*t_i) , for a_(ii) entry and k=1,2,..,n ,

-p_i*t_i , for a_((n+i)i) entry , and

d_i , for a_((n+i)(n+i)) entry.

I tried for i=2, and 3, but when I tried i=4, my program wont end.
Here is my program:

```
    from sympy import *
    from numpy import matrix
    from numpy import linalg
    from sympy import Matrix

    Ab, Ac, Ad, Ba, Bc, Bd, Ca, Cb, Cd, Da, Db, Dc, Za, Zb, Zc, Zd, Xa, Xb, 
    Xc, Xd, Ya, Yb, Yc, Yd = symbols('Ab, Ac, Ad, Ba, Bc, Bd, Ca, Cb, Cd, Da, 
    Db, Dc, Za, Zb, Zc, Zd, Xa, Xb, Xc, Xd, Ya, Yb, Yc, Yd')
    V = Matrix([[Ab+Ab+Ad+Za, -Ba, -Ca, -Da, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [-Ab, Ba+Bc+Bd+Zb, -Cb, -Db, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [-Ac, -Bc, Ca+Cb+Cd+Zc, -Dc, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [-Ad, -Bd, -Cd, Da+Db+Dc+Zd, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [-Xa, 0, 0, 0, Ya, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, -Xb, 0, 0, 0, Yb, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, -Xc, 0, 0, 0, Yc, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, -Xd, 0, 0, 0, Yd]])
    V_inverse = V.inv()
    print("V'=", V_inverse)
```

Here, I substitute
m_(12) = Ab,  m_(13) = Ac,  m_(14) = Ad,

m_(21) = Ba, m_(23) = Bc, m_(24) = Bd,

m_(31) = Ca, m_(32) = Cb, m_(34) = Cd,

m_(41) = Da, m_(42) = Db, m_(43) = Dc,

y_1 = Ya, y_2 = Yb, y_3 = Yc, y_4 = Yd,

p_1*t_1 = Xa, p_2*t_2 = Xb, p_3*t_3 = Xc, p_4*t_4 = Xd.

Thank you.

Comment: You use different variable names from what you first explain in formulas. So it is hard to see any correlation. What are *y_i*, *p_i*, *t_i*, *d_i*?

Comment: Thannk you sir. I tried edit my post.

Comment: It's nice when you make the example something that can be cut and paste: variable names can't have parentheses in them. But that aside, what are you going to do with the symbolic expression when you find it? If you are going to put in values for the symbols, consider doing that *before* trying to find the inverse.

Comment: That's what I did before I edited my post sir. Thank you.

Comment: I edit my code here sir @smichr. Thank you.

Comment: Sir @trincot, y_i, p_i, etc, are variables. Thank you.

Comment: If you have numerical values for the variables, use those instead of the symbols or use `subs` method to replace the symbols with numbers *before* trying to compute the inverse. A symbolic inverse for a matrix this size is going to be unwieldy (as you are finding).